# npm install always goes for the local package instead of a remote

Tags: npm-install

I have created project `my-npm-lib` and published it with npm.

Now I have an another project where I want to do:

`npm install my-npm-lib --save`

But if I do so, it always add to dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-npm-lib": "file:..\\my-npm-lib"
}
```

> This is actually correct because I have the my-npm-lib project located there on the device where I do this.

But this is something I don't want to. Later in my new project I use the webpack and I need to do:

```
include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/my-npm-lib")
],
```

which

1. is impossible now because the module is not located in node_modules,
2. doesn't allow me to share the new project correctly with other associates, because there is a wrong path in the `package.json` file.

So far I have tried to rewrite the `package.json` manually with

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-npm-lib": "^1.0.0"
}
```

and then use `npm install`, but it didn't install this particular module.

> PS: Im quite sure my-npm-lib is working with npm, because it is working on other device. It seems there is a problem only with the device where the my-npm-lib is being developed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution,

be sure that `package.json` dependencies has a correct structure,

use `npm install my-npm-lib --save`,

then rewrite the `"file:..\\my-npm-lib"` to `"^1.0.0"`,

delete the `package-lock.json`!, **(it was the missing piece)**

cast `npm install` again.